# C# World Grid Assistance

Tags: c#, .net, list

I am trying to build a World Grid with Sheep and Wolf ( Predictor Prey Application with Sheep feeding on Grass and Wolf feeding on Sheep ) and I need to build a World Grid and i am not sure which Class to choose List or which one? can someone please guide me with the program please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a grid with a fixed size, it's best to use a two-dimensional array.  If you world consists of objects of type `Place`, for instance, you would define this as `Place[,] worldGrid = new Place[width, length];`.

`Place` would be a type that might contain sheep or wolves or grass.

```
enum Organism { Wolf, Sheep, Grass };

class Place
{
  public List<Organism> Inhabitants { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: a place can contain Wolf Sheep and Grass at the same time then how do i do it?

Comment: @softplaza: Simply make it contain a list of organisms.  I'll edit my example.

Comment: You can also have something like IOrganism which is inherited by three clases (wolf, sheep, grass) if you don't like enums. The IOrganism would just be an empty interface

Comment: I am new to C# please help me this is my final project :( and i have less time

Comment: @softplaza: You sound pretty desperate.  Would it help if you selected a language you are more familiar with (assuming you have that option)?  If it has to be C#, you might be better off grabbing a book and learning the basics in a less frantic manner.

Comment: `List<Organism>` is overkill for this problem. instead define `enum Organism { Nothing = 0, Wolf = 1, Sheep = 2, Grass = 4, x = 8, y = 16 };` then using bitwise OR you could find out what things exist in one place. check [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx) for some more info. **Example** `P1.Organisms = Organism.Wolf | Organism.Sheep;` **value = 3 (1 | 2)**

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar Hiremath: That's a good solution, as long as there can never be multiple of each organism in a location.  (And you never expand the number of organisms beyond 64.)